# Favorite Tags displacement by ads

Tags: discussion

This is something that annoyed me for some time now.

At the homepage of SO the favorite/ignored tags are all displayed at the top of the screen right below the "Ask Question"-button.

Like this:
[image]

Yet when I navigate to the Questions when I press the "Questions"-button they get displaced to underneath the ads all the sudden.

Like this:
[image]

Can anyone tell me if this is intentional or just one of my personal annoyances?

Comment: No repro here with FF9.

Comment: I'm using Safari, would that be the issue here?

Comment: Successful repro in Chrome. Top-level "Unanswered" page behaves (similarly) to the home page, but all sub-tabs under the top-level Questions tab has adds over top of the fave tags.

Comment: This seems like the sort of thing that a rep-level "achievement" could determine...high-level rep puts adverts _under_ the fave tags (or somewhere else)

Comment: Well I just think it needs to be consistent in any case.

Comment: This is still a problem 8 months later :(